# how to install curl in latest python?

Tags: python, curl, python-3.3

When I'm googling everywhere it is pointed to http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/

but when I try to install this package I get :

```
d:\pycurl>setup.py -install d:\curl\
  File "d:\pycurl\setup.py", line 58
    print "FATAL: bad directory %s in environment variable %s" % (dir, envvar)
                                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package is not compatible with Python 3; you'll have to request the author ports it. There is [an existing patch](http://sourceforge.net/p/pycurl/patches/12/) you could try out.

In the meantime, look into other libraries instead, the [`requests` library](https://requests.readthedocs.io/) *does* support Python 3 and has a *far* superior API to `pycurl`.